# Regex validation letters, dots and dash Laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I have this validation:

```
'users.first_name' => 'required|min:2|regex:/[A-Za-z. -]/|max:255',
```

Why this validation pass this name: John[][]

Comment: Please give us a [mcve] so we can reproduce your problem

Comment: @lonVasile What you need to allow in `first_name`??

Comment: Any letter, dot and dash.

Comment: Try `'users.first_name' => 'required|regex:/^[A-Za-z. -]{2,255}$/'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Someone in comments also pointed to this issue that by `/[A-Za-z. -]/` you don't care about all characters but saying that's enough for me if field under validation has only the least of that characters.

To have only those characters you should specify beginning and ending of the input text by using a caret `^` and `$`:

```
regex:/^[A-Za-z. -]+$/
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I had similar requirements for a username minus allowing the space character and I needed to allow numbers. So all usernames can have numbers, letters a-z both upper and lowercase, underscores, dots and dashes. This works for Laravel 5.4, here's the end result : `'username'              => ['required', 'regex:/^[0-9A-Za-z.\-_]+$/', 'max:150'],`

Comment: Thank you @racl101. It still works on Laravel 7. In my case I declared a `Rule` class and used your regex there. Also I considered appropriate adding `'min:3'`.

Answer (score 2):

use [Alpha dash validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-alpha-dash)

```
'users.first_name' => 'required|min:2|alpha_dash|max:255',
```

Comment: *`alpha_dash` - The field under validation may have alpha-numeric characters, as well as dashes and underscores.* - What about a dot and space?

Comment: Oh! my bad. didn't see the . dot. Btw I don't know why first name will include a dot.

Comment: Initial of father.

Comment: alpha_dash is also allowing numerics, which first name probably don't use either. :)